# App crash when updating from old build to new build on testflight

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, testflight

I have created an app that crashing when tried on testflight to update from build 54 to 55. But if I delete the app first, then install the build 55 it runs smoothly. so I build another one with some fixes inside and try it on test flight, so now build 55 - 56 update. it runs smoothly.

so the problem is that when updating from 54 to 55 something off, is anyone here has had the same problem?

Comment: What does crash tell?

Comment: are you using any database? Migration calls!

Comment: change in userdefaults values or anything related to it... most suitable solution is if you have your code commit before 54 and after 54 try to install 54 then 54 and you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: check database, userdefaults related

Comment: @dreamBegin you mean 54 then 55 then 56? I will try this tomorrow, hope that this can be simulated in simulator. I am a new dev on this project so tomorrow I will track it down.

Comment: @karthikeyan ok ill check them out

Comment: @kirander, i dont know yet, I'll try to debug this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, if you have a crash on an update and not on a fresh install, it means that you have some persisting data that is not compatible with the state of the updated app.

The most common cases are :

- Database data is not migrated properly (or not migrated at all) ; maybe between the two updates some of the fields changed in code and are not compatible with older database version?
- Keys & values in keychain and/or userdefaults. Same as the database, your code is expecting some values but the file from the previous versions does not know those values.
- Files. You might be writing/expecting some files formatted in a specific way, or containing specific data. But users from earlier versions might not have those files, and therefore would cause a crash

Basically, anything that persists can cause crashes or bugs when updating to a new version. But because you're testing from a fresh install, you always get the correct formats during your tests.

If you have a crash, there should be a very clear exception telling you what happened which can help you locate the issue, and why it happened. It should be pretty simple from there to isolate the files that require migrations.

Good solutions to avoid that is to test using previous versions installed, and keep track of all persistant modifications that you make. Once you decide something that has to persist, you have to take it into account once you decide to change it. You'll probably have to write some code to update the file and check its version before accessing it. So if database version 1 had two tables and three fields, you have to know it, and if you're not happy with that, you have to write code to update the database, all of its contents, and then only you can expect everyone to have the new database.

This is also another good idea : use versioning inside your app. If your app is version 40, but your file is still in version 34 format, you have to update it to version 40 using code specific for that update.

Migrating is not an easy task. Requires a lot of testing and data manipulation. I strongly suggest you use unit tests for that kind of work before pushing into production.

Comment: yeah i got it working last time because NSUserDefault. Thank you Gil!